# How to change swatch from grid view to list view

Tags: product, database

I'm new one here. I have no experience with magento developing.
I want to change my product swatch from list view to grid or grid view to list view.
I have also attached a picture of my  product page. Is there anyone available for my help. Please
[image]

Comment: Do you use any kind of module to do that?

Comment: Yes I'm using the module advance product custom option templates of mageworx

Answer (score 0):

Go to Store->Attributes->Product->(Attribute name)->Catalog Input Type for Store Owner->Dropdown->Save->Clear Cache

Done.

Comment: Can't dropdown Catalog Input Type for Store Owner.
I also want to inform you that I'm using Mageworx Extension( Product Custom Option Templates). I have not added any swatch to in attribute. It's all by module

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the module but based on the module you should be able to. Try checking out the store demo of the module and check the configurations there:

[image]

[Mageworx extension](https://www.mageworx.com/magento-2-advanced-product-options-suite.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have same setting as in your given screenshot but did not working.